# Curl in Android HERE Maps

Tags: android, curl, here-api

How can I implement curl command in Android? I am using `https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_id=appid&app_code=appcode&at=52.5304417,13.4111201&q=rest&pretty` but it does not return JSON file. It returns an HTML page.I want to do search on the maps and show nearby restaurants.

```
    curl \
  --compressed \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' \
  -H 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5' \
  --get 'https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code=appcode' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id=appid' \
    --data-urlencode 'at=52.5304417,13.4111201' \
    --data-urlencode 'pretty=true' \
    --data-urlencode 'q=rest'
```

Comment: Did you try to add header "Accept:application/json"? in case of curl -H 'Accept:application/json'

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you've just published your app id and app code publicly. They are very likely going to be abused. You should probably delete the project associated with these credentials and create a new one to prevent this.

Comment: yes, I had taken care of that, please provide the answer to the question as well